# Is the password actually hidden in 'read -s' in Linux/Unix shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p " Enter Username :" USERNAME
read -p " Enter Password :" -s PASSWORD
```

**ps -ef** doesn't show any details, it hides the password. But, is this really a safe approach from Information Security perspective?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Safe for what, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the session is transmitted using a secure transport such as SSH or locally, it should be secure. It helps that `read` is a shell builtin command.

The value of the variables inside a running bash sessions are not exported to the environment of the bash process itself.

*One thing to be aware of:*
If you `export` the `PASSWORD` environment variable and then launch an external command, the content of the variable will be exposed (and visible for example by `ps e`).

You can test this like this:

```
read -s PASSWORD
export PASSWORD
sleep 999
```

Search for the "sleep" process and you will see PASSWORD and its value.
Environment variables are not a confidential way to pass data to processes.

If you want to handle the secret data stored in the environment variable, make sure you stick to shell builtin commands such as `echo`.

Comment: 'it should be secure' is not really meaningful without some definition of the sort of threat it's supposed to be secure against. If this process, say, dumps core, the plaintext password would be in it.

Comment: @pvg What process would generate a core dump in this? Bash? How likely is that to happen when reading text from a terminal into a script?